# i want to print system date as git commit message using groovy script

Tags: git, groovy

i want to print system date as git commit message using groovy. Nothing is output using below code.

```
Date date = new Date();
def command = "git commit -a -m '$date'"

Process process = command.execute(null, new File('C:/git/dev1/server')) 
println(process.text)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you do not get any output, you probably have some output on `stderr`, you just check `stdout` with `.text`. Look into `.err.text` to find the error message.

Comment: Std Err: error: pathspec 'Nov' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec '29' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec '16:13:09' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec 'IST' did not match any file(s) known to git.
error: pathspec '2017'' did not match any file(s) known to git.
Std Out:
@Vampire....It is taking date as a file parameter i think..Just need to know how can i commit with  date as commit message.

Comment: Well, you see, something is not correct with your escaping of arguments maybe you better use `['git', 'commit', '-a', '-m', date].execute(null, new File(...))` then you don't need any escaping as one list element is one parameter.